# Computed property on a model in a different controller

Tags: ember.js

I'm building the mandatory TODO app to learn ember.

I have tasks and tags in a belongsTo/hasMany relationship (each tag hasMany tasks). When showing tasks, I want to show a computed property on each available tag.

**Models:**

```
App.Tag = DS.Model.extend({
  tasks: DS.hasMany('task', {async: true}),
  ..
});

App.Task = DS.Model.extend({
  tag: DS.belongsTo('tag', {async: true}),
  ..
});
```

**Route:**

```
App.TasksRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

  model: function(params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      tasks: this.store.find('task'),
      tags: this.store.find('tag')
    });
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this.controllerFor('tasks').set('content', model.tasks);
    this.controllerFor('tags').set('content', model.tags);
  }
});
```

**Tags controller:**

```
App.TagsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({  
  needs: ["tag"]
})
```

**Tag controller:**

```
App.TagController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

  taskCount: function() {
    // FOLLOWING DOES NOT WORK
    return this.get('tasks.length')
  }.property('tasks')

});
```

**Tag partial:**

```
<ul>
  {{#each tag in model}}
    <li>
      {{tag.name}} ({{controllers.tag.taskCount}} tasks)
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

The computed property 'taskCount' does not work. There is something wrong with 'this'.

Is this canonical way of doing it? And if so, what is wrong? Thanks

**EDIT: FIXED**
I had missed out
    App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend();
And I've used render to get the controller decoration:
    {{render 'tag' tag}}
which calls the controller before rendering

Comment: You are never setting `tasks` to the `TagController` whats the relationship between this to supposed to be, and where is it defined?

Comment: I've added relevant bits of the models to show their relationship.

Comment: I fixed this and have edited to describe it